# using Jsoup to sign in and crawl data

Tags: java, cookies, jsoup

I want to use `Jsoup` to crawl a page that is only available when I signed in. I guess it means I need to sign in on one page and send cookies to another page.
I read some earlier post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie) and write the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("login.yahoo.com")
        .data("login", "myusername", "passwd", "mypassword")
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document doc=res.parse();
String sessionId = res.cookie("SESSIONID");

Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://health.groups.yahoo.com/group/asthma/messages")
        .cookie("SESSIONID", sessionId)
        .get();

Elements Eles=doc2.getElementsByClass("message");

String content=Eles.first().text();

System.out.println(content);
```

My question is how I can know my cookie name (i.e. "SESSIONID") here for sending my login info? I used the `.cookies()` method to get all the cookies from the login page:

> B
>   DK
>   YM
>   T
>   PH
>   Y
>   F

I tried them one by one but none worked. I could get sessionId from some of them, but I could not successfully get nodes from the second page, which means I didn't successfully sign in. Could anyone give me some suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: Yahoo has many cookies, performs login over https, and other security implications.

Answer (score 7):

Ive struggled with logging in to websites with jsoup also.

What i came up with was a hybrid of selenium webdriver, and jsoup.

Webdriver can remote control a browser, typically this is used for testing purposes.

For my application, it was not desirable to have the browser visible, and messing about on the screen. So I have used the "silent" webdriver: HtmlUnitDriver instead. You can instantiate this using this line of code:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(true); // true meaning javascript support (Using rhino i be leave)
```

Now to login to a website i use:

```
String baseUrl = "http://www.thesite.com";

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get(baseUrl);

driver.findElement(By.id("TextBoxUser")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("TextBoxUser")).sendKeys("username");
driver.findElement(By.id("TextBoxPass")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.id("TextBoxPass")).sendKeys("password");
driver.findElement(By.id("Button1")).click();
```

Get the page content:

```
String htmlContent = driver.getPageSource();
```

Start using jsoup:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(htmlContent);
```

This has worked great for me.

Steffn Otto Jensen

Comment: One thing I'd like to add, make sure you add the `HtmlUnitDriver` jar, in addition to the regular selenium ones. Other than that, thanks so much, after 6 hours of frustration with Jsoup, this was a lifesaver

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to do something like this:

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?")
    .data("login", "myusername", "passwd", "mypassword")
    .method(Method.POST)
    .execute();

 Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

 Connection connection = Jsoup.connect("http://health.groups.yahoo.com/group/asthma/messages");

 for (Map.Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
     connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());     
 }

 Document doc=  connection.get();
 // #code selector
 // Example
 // Element e=doc.select(".ygrp-grdescr").first();
 // System.out.println(e.text()); // Print => This list will be for asthmatics, and anyone whose       life is affected by it. Discussions include causes, problems, and treatment
```

I hope you this works for your problem.