# web page source downloaded through Jsoup is not equal to the actual web page source

Tags: java, html, url, jsoup

i have a severe concern here. i have searched all through stack overflow and many other sites. every where they give the same solution and i have tried all those but mi am not able to resolve this issue.

i have the following code,

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(30000).get();
```

Here m using Jsoup library and the result that i am getting is not equal to the actual page source that we can see but right click on the page -> page source. Many parts are missing in the result that i am getting with the above line of code.
After searching some sites on Google, i saw this methid,

```
URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);



        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();          

        System.out.println(result);
```

But no Luck.
While i was searching over the internet for this problem i saw many sites where it said i had to set the proper charSet and encoding types of the webpage while downloading the page source of a web page. but how will i get to know these things from my code dynamically?? is there any classes in java for that. i went through crawler4j also a bit but it did not to much for me. Please help guys. m stuck with this problem for over a month now. i have tried all my ways i can. so final hope is on the gods of stack overflow who have always helped!!

Comment: Maybe the page source is malformed HTML and JSoup is cleaning it up by removing the invalid sections?

Comment: hi dnault, the webpage is from a well hosted website so i think it would have gone through validations and it might not be a malformed HTML

Answer (score 5):

I had this recently. I'd run into some sort of robot protection. Change your original line to:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .get();
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be that your web page is rendered by Javascript which is run in a browser, JSoup alone can't help you with this, so you may try using HtmlUnit which uses Selenium to emulate the browser: [using Jsoup to sign in and crawl data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156019/using-jsoup-to-sign-in-and-crawl-data).

**UPDATE**

There are several reasons why HTML is different. The most probable is that this web page contains `<javascript>` elements which contains dynamic page logic. This could be an application inside your web page which sends requests to the server and add or removes content depending on the responses.

JSoup would never render such pages because it's a job for a browser like Chrome, Firefox or IE. JSoup is a lightweight parser for plaintext html you get from the server.

So what you could do is you could use a web driver which emulates a web browser and renders a page in memory, so it would have the same content as shown to the user. You may even do mouse clicks with this driver.

And the proposed implementation for the web driver in the linked answer is HtmlUnit. It's the most lightweight solution, however, it's might give you unexpected results: [Selenium vs HtmlUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807689/selenium-vs-htmlunit).

If you want the most real page rendering, you might want to consider [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41132/discussion-between-user2781031-and-andrey-chaschev)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to parse a web page this way? If there is a consumable service available from the website, the website might have an [REST API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer).

To answer your question, A webpage viewed using the web-browser **may** not be same, as the same webpage is downloaded using a [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

The following could be few of the reasons that cause these differences:

1. [Request Headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields): when the client (java application/browser) makes a request for a URL, it sets various headers as part of the request and the webserver may change the content of the response accordingly.
2. [Java Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4243055/how-do-browsers-handle-javascript): once the response is recieved, if there are java script elements present in the response it's executed by the browsers javascript engine, which may change the contents of [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model).
3. Browser Plugins, such as IE Browser Helper Objects, Firefox Extensions or Chrome Extensions may change the contents of the DOM.

in simple terms, when you request a URL using a URLConnection you are recieving raw data, however when you request the same URL using a browser's addressbar you get processed (by javascript/browser plugins) webpage.

URLConnection/JSoup will allow you to set request headers as required, but you may still get the different response due to points 2 & 3. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) allows you to remote control a browser and has a api to access the rendered page. Selenium is used for automated testing of web applications.