# Java Jsoup get session expired when access data/information from webservice

Tags: web-services, session, jsoup

I need to get some information using java jsoup from asp webservice. I also have read link: [jsoup posting and cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie), but i still confused. Here is my code:

```
//1.Create connection to server
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.server.com/user.aspx?lang=en-us")
                    .timeout(50000).data("{\"userid\":\"subagent01\",\"password\":\"mypassword\"}", "")
                    .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();
Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();
Document doc = res.parse();

//2.Get information form server
String fAddressUrl = "http://www.server.com/WebService/Service.asmx/getSchedule?fromCity=CityA&toCity=CityB";
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(fAddressUrl).cookies(cookies).get();
System.out.println(doc2);
```

And i got this reply:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   Error, session is session_expired
  </string>
 </body>
</html>
```

If also tried to call directly that url ("http://www.server.com/WebService/Service.asmx/getSchedule?fromCity=CityA&toCity=CityB") in web browser, and here are the result:

1.With doing login first at www.server.com
  -> Success. I got the information in web browser

2.Without doing login at www.server.com
  -> Failed. Display the same error, "Error, session is session_expired".

So, what is the problem?

Comment: I tried using other library like HtmlUnit and it works.