# jsoup record logged

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup, httpresponse

I have a website.

Can see inside the contents must be logged in.

However, I use this code to log on.

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://46.137.207.181/Account/Login.aspx")
                  .data("ctl00$MainContent$LoginUser$UserName", "1234")
                  .data("ctl00$MainContent$LoginUser$Password", "123456")
                  .data("__VIEWSTATE","/wEPDwULLTEyMDAyNTY1NjJkGAEFHl9fQ29udHJvbHNSZXF1aXJlUG9zdEJhY2tLZXlfXxYBBSZjdGwwMCRNYWluQ29udGVudCRMb2dpblVzZXIkUmVtZW1iZXJNZUHk9FMvtsvPHqlP3vAV+1oloaxe4Asr7RQX5XFptqGz")
                  .data("__EVENTVALIDATION","/wEWBQLup8mjCgLFyvjkDwLQzbOWAgKVu47QDwKnwKnjBTL6Xsxc9zQnY8p9KVlFJ/8HIHqlOGl9uClF4ktcWYJ5")
                  .data("ctl00$MainContent$LoginUser$LoginButton","2")
                  request.
                  .post();
```

Then get the login pages.

```
doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://46.137.207.181/Groups.aspx").get();
            s=doc.title();
            Elements kelime = doc.select("td");
            for (Element link : kelime) {
                  linkHref = link.attr("hh");
```

Have shown no login screen.

I would like to ask how can I do it?

Comment: Does the authentication require cookies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening in your example is that you are logging in with form data to `Login.apsx` and creating a session, but the request to `Groups.aspx` doesn't carry that session data, so the request is not authenticated.

`Login.aspx` will return a session cookie, and you need to pass that cookie onto the next request.

See the answers to this [jsoup login question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6476916/153184) for good examples.