# Jsoup Login with a Selection Element

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup

my Boss told me to write a HTML parser which is fetching some table datas....
well, I´m stuck here and there and really need your help :)

First of all, I need to login to the website, and then navigate to another url ( I hope that it will work with cookies) and fetching the datas.

The Loginform got the Username & Password field and a selection list with a lot of options, I like to choose the second option..how I can do this?

Here are my code I already got:

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\unicert.jks");
 Response res = Jsoup.connect("URL to Loginform")
                    .data("u", "UsernameHere")
                    .data("p", "PasswortHere")
                    .data("r", "Second Option")
                    .method(Method.POST).execute();

Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies(); //Getting the Cookies
Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(loginCookies).get(); //loading new Site with Cookies
```

I would love to here from you :) thanks a lot!
Alex

Comment: If I were you, I would connect, login and navigate to proper resource using Apache HTTP Client, and later on parse retrieved HTML with Jsoup using `Jsoup.parse(String html)`. At least I always do such things that way in my workplace.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie. As for the second option, as the key, you will put the name of the input, and value, the value of the input. Just inspect the element with firebug (or such).

Comment: thanks a lot, could you give me please a example? I dont get it what you mean with inspecting the element?