# Login to Facebook with Jsoup and proper cookies

Tags: java, facebook, cookies, jsoup

I am currently trying to automatically scrap my own home page and possibly other pages that I have access to when logged in to facebook. However I can't seem to be "logged" in after using the code below and setting the cookie.

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1")
            .data("email", "#####", "pass", "#####").userAgent("Mozilla")
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

    Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();

        try{
            Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/")
                .cookies(cookies).post();
            System.out.println(doc2.text());
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

When I do this it will just send me back the facebook home page as though I were not logged in. When I try my own about page I get

```
HTTP error fetching URL. Status=404
```

Am I doing something wrong here? Are there other fields I need to set?
I found another post that said other fields need to be set but I haven't the slightest clue how to find this information. The post can be found here [Login Facebook via Jsoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851747/login-facebook-via-jsoup)

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851747/login-facebook-via-jsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see a example here: [How to Login on Facebook w/ Jsoup](https://www.jhonatansouza.com/2018/08/login-on-facebook-w-jsoup.html)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Response req;
    try {
        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36";

        req = Jsoup.connect("https://m.facebook.com/login/async/?refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2F&lwv=100")
            .userAgent(userAgent)
            .method(Method.POST).data("email", "YOUR_EMAIL").data("pass", "YOUR_PASSWORD")
            .followRedirects(true).execute();

        Document d = Jsoup.connect("https://m.facebook.com/profile.php?ref=bookmarks").userAgent(userAgent)
            .cookies(req.cookies()).get();

        System.out.println(d.body().text().toString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```