# Facebook login via JSoup or another browser emulator

Tags: java, facebook, web-scraping, jsoup

There is already a question like this [(here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19851747/login-facebook-via-jsoup) but mine is different.

Facebook login form needs some request headers and hidden fields as well.

```
lsd
local
timezone
default_persistent
lgnrnd
lgnjs
qsstamp
```

where `local, timezone, default_persistent` can be static values, but afaik `lsd, lgnrnd, lgnjs, qsstamp` are dymanic fields and their values change for each login visit, my guess is they have it there to prevent emulated logins like i am doing. qsstamp field does not even exist on page load. Values `lgnjs and qsstamp` are calculated via Javascript in facebook welcome page.

My question is Jsoup does not emulate javascript, then how do i get correct values for these fields to get through login of facebook?