# How to crawl a website after login in it with username and password

Tags: java, jsoup, web-crawler

I have written a webcrawler that crawls a website with keyward but i want to login to my specified website and filter information by keyword.How to achive that. i posting my code so far i have done .

```
public class DB {

public Connection conn = null;

public DB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root","root");
        System.out.println("conn built");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet runSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.executeQuery(sql);
}

public boolean runSql2(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.execute(sql);
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if (conn != null || !conn.isClosed()) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
}


public class Main {
public static DB db = new DB();

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
    db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
    processPage("http://m.naukri.com/login");
}

public static void processPage(String URL) throws SQLException, IOException{
    //check if the given URL is already in database;
    String sql = "select * from Record where URL = '"+URL+"'";
    ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
    if(rs.next()){

    }else{
        //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
        sql = "INSERT INTO  `test`.`Record` " + "(`URL`) VALUES " + "(?);";
        PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        stmt.setString(1, URL);
        stmt.execute();

        //get useful information
        Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://www.naukri.com/").data("username","jeet.chatterjee.88@gmail.com","password","Letmein321")
                 .method(Method.POST)
                    .execute();  
        //http://m.naukri.com/login
        Map<String, String> loginCookies = res.cookies();
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.naukri.com/login")
                  .cookies(loginCookies)
                  .get();

        if(doc.text().contains("")){
            System.out.println(URL);
        }

        //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
        Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
        for(Element link: questions){
            if(link.attr("abs:href").contains("naukri.com"))
                processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the table structure also

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Record` (
 `RecordID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `URL` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RecordID`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Now i want to use my username and password for that crawling so that crawler can log in to the site dynamically and crawl infomation on the basis of keyword..
Lets say my username is lucifer & password is lucifer123

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804209/what-are-sessions-how-do-they-work

Comment: And after that see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie

Comment: i have tried  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.nki.com/login").data("Username","jeet.chatterjee.88@gmail.com","Password","mypass").post(); but stil unable to login to that site

Comment: When i am trying that code the site is giving me two URL s one for forget password and another one for register

Comment: Can anyone tell where i am doing wrong??

Comment: Not unless you provide runnable code that we can copy and test.

Comment: OK i am editing my original post with the complete code

Comment: try log in from browser and add cookie that is saved in your browser to your code ( do it fast or session will expire and you have to do it again)

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc have you find anything wrong iin my code??

Comment: @alizelzele is that anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 5):

your approach is for stateless web access, which usually works for web services. sites are stateful. you authenticate once and after that, they use the session key stored in your cookie to authenticate you ( other means of authentication is also possible), so it is required. you must send parameters that your browser is sending. try monitoring what your browser send to site with firebug, and reproduce that in your code

**--update--**

```
Jsoup.connect("url")
  .cookie("cookie-name", "cookie-value")
  .header("header-name", "header-value")
  .data("data-name","data-value");
```

u can add multi cookie | header | data. and there is function for adding values from `Map`.

to find out what must be set, add fire bug to your browser, they all have their default developer console which can be started with `F12`. go to the url u want to get data and just add all thing in there to your jsoup request.
i added some images from your site result
[image: capture]

i marked important part in red.

u can get required cookies in your code with sending these info to site and get cookie from that and after getting response.cookies you attach these cookies to every request u make ;)

p.s: change your password A.S.A.P

Comment: i did not complete get u ,can you give me some example?

Comment: @alizezele i will try your code ,Thanks for reply..BTW are you able to login to that site using my credentials??

Comment: your login information was all in `Jsoup.connect("http://www.naukri.com/").data("username","jeet.chatterjee.88@gmail.com","password","Letmein321")` so that is not that hard to login ;). by the way i test it again and password is changed(hopefully by you)

Comment: yes i am just asking that were you able to login in the website with my code?? i am asking about manual login

Comment: your code is completely wrong. the url that check for login is not home page. it is `/nlogin/login.php`. i have not tried your code but i am pretty sure than wount work ;)