# Login at Istock using Jsoup

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

Im trying to login into istockphoto using jsoup but give me always wrong pass, the user and pass are both correct

**code**

```
String user = "myUser";
String pass = "myPass";


Connection doc = Jsoup.connect("https://secure.istockphoto.com/sign-in/");

String token = doc.get().body().getElementById("signInFormtoken").val();
Response res = doc
     .data("signInFormtoken",token, "identity", user, "credential", pass, "submit", "Sign In"   )
     .method(Method.POST)
     .execute();

System.out.println(res.body());

Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect("http://www.istockphoto.com/my_uploads.php").cookies(res.cookies()).get();

System.out.println(doc2.title());
```

**form code**

```
<form id="signInForm" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" action="" method="post"><dl class="zend_form">

<input type="hidden" name="signInFormtoken" value="YToxOntzOjU6InRva2VuIjtzOjMyOiI1M2M5ZmNhZjBhZWZjOTVlZDA3ZDVkNTZlOTg5Y2VjYSI7fQ==" id="signInFormtoken">
<label for="identity" Id="identityLabel" class="optional">Email or Member Name</label>

<input type="text" name="identity" id="identity" value="">
<label for="credential" Id="credentialLabel" class="optional">Password</label>

<input type="password" name="credential" id="credential" value="">

<img id="signInSpinner" class="h mt8" src="https://i.istockimg.com/static/images/loading.gif">

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="sign-in-submit" value="Sign In">

<a id="lost-password-link" href="/istock_lostpassword.php" class="lostPasswordLink">Forgot your password?</a></dl></form>
```

The login page is https://secure.istockphoto.com/sign-in/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Add a userAgent to your connection.

Comment: Save cookie and send it with your next requests.

Comment: See this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie

Comment: @LittlePanda i don't get any error, just fail the login, the userAgent is added ( `.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6") `  ), still failing, the -> `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` <- could influence ?

Comment: I have seen the examples on that question. Can you try just passing the username and password in your `.data("username",username, "password", pass).method(Method.POST).timeout(5000).execute();`?

Comment: @LittlePanda still dont work, and the `signInFormtoken`  is dynamic

Comment: Jsoup does not support JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest Selenium + PhantomJSDriver (Ghostdriver), which is used for **GUI-less** browser automation. With this you can easily navigate through the pages, select elements (you can select the flights), submit forms and also perform some scraping. *Javascript is also supported.*

You can got through the Selenium documentation [**here**](http://www.seleniumhq.org/). You will have to download [**phantomjs.exe**](http://phantomjs.org/) file.

A good tutorial forPhantomJSDriver is given in [**here**](http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2013/03/headless-browser-testing-using.html)

Config of PhantomJSDriver(from the tutorial):

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true); // not really needed: JS enabled by default
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY, "C://phantomjs.exe");
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```