# How to post login data using jsoup

Tags: android, web-scraping, jsoup

I want to simulate a login and then scrape some content while maintaining the logged-in session. I've got it working using HtmlUnit, but was looking into Jsoup since I want it to work on Android as well.

loginUrl = https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/login/j_security_check

usageUrl =  https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/application/index.jsp?page=usage ; this is the page that I need extract information from.

[UPDATE -- ]

Thanks to [greenapps](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2108972/greenapps), I've finally been able to login successfully. Just had to change the loginUrl, from `../login/login.jsp` to `../login/j_security_check`

Here's the working code:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(loginUrl)
                                  .data("j_username", myUserName)
                                  .data("j_password", myPassword)
                                  .method(Method.POST).execute();

Document usageDoc = Jsoup.connect(usageUrl).cookies(response.cookies()).get();

System.out.print(usageDoc.toString());
```

But now the problem is, once logged in, some content that are generated through JS are shown blank or empty. Is there a workaround to get those values show up?

Comment: @greenapps [HtmlUnit. Java GUI-Less browser](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: It does not seem to load the desired page. Well you are trying to load two pages. Please explain better what happens and not happens. What kind of 'response' do you get from first page?

Comment: @greenapps [loginUrl](https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/login/login.jsp) is the login page. Once logged in I should be able to load the usage page through the [usageUrl](https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/application/index.jsp?page=usage) (which in case the desired page)

Comment: You are telling nothing new. I knew that already.

Comment: @greenapps I'm trying to explain as best as I could : )

Comment: But you did not answer my question: `What kind of 'response' do you get from first page?`. So what is 'best'?

Comment: What you need to do is save the cookie it gives you, and send it with the next request. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie. Tell me if that works.

Comment: @JonasCz I'm passing the cookies using `response.cookies()`  as you could see in the second statement.

Comment: Sorry, did't see that. Did you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/10533408/4428462 ?

Comment: @JonasCz yup I did.  Please have a look on source the code for the submit button. I updated the question btw.

Comment: You should post the complete <form> of course so we can see all the parameters.

Comment: Your loginUrl should be `https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/login/j_security_check`. As you can see in `<form id="login_form" action="j_security_check" method="post">`.Maybe you have to add a .jsp. I don't know.

Comment: @greenapps yeah, that does work. but .. please see the edited post

Comment: `content that are generated through JS`. What is JS? And where do we see content here?

Comment: @greenapps I mean JavaScript.

Comment: Yes of course the java scipt will not be executed by Jsoup. You better use HtmlUnit ;-).

Comment: HtmlUnit does not support Android. That's why I'm checking into Jsoup

Comment: Then you maybe can use a WebView?

Answer (score 1):

Your loginUrl should be `https://www.internetvas.slt.lk/SLTVasPortal-war/login/j_security_check1`. As you can see in `<form id="login_form" action="j_security_check" method="post">`.

Comment: Url should be `j_security_check` and not `_check1`, right?