# Login to a website using Jsoup and stay on the site

Tags: java, android, http, post, jsoup

I try to log in here: http://www.gszi.sulinet.hu/dinaweb/diakok/belepes.jsp
with this:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gszi.sulinet.hu/dinaweb/diakok/belepes.jsp")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gszi.sulinet.hu/dinaweb/diakok/belepes.jsp")
            .data("name","myid")
            .data("name","mycode")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .post();
```

Afterwards, getting the html of a page which I have to login to see, I realize that I couldn't log in. Is there a way to login and then get the html of pages I have access now? Any link, advice or help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, actually I have found that I need one more parameter ("akcio") and I sent post() method to the wrong URL now my program runs properly, my code:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl)
         .method(Connection.Method.GET)
         .execute();

    Map<String, String> loginCookies = loginForm.cookies();

    Document document = Jsoup
        .connect(loginFormUrl)
        .data("akcio", akcio)
        .data("felnev",felnev)
        .data("jelszo",jelszo)
        .cookies(loginCookies)
        .post();

    Document document2 = Jsoup.connect(loggedInUrl)
    .cookies(loginCookies)
    .get();
    System.out.println(document2);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using the same key for two different input tags. Moreover the keys you are using are wrong.

```
.data("jelszo","SOMETEXT")
.data("felnev","PASSWORD")
```

**Update**

```
Connection.Response initial = Jsoup
        .connect("http://www.gszi.sulinet.hu/dinaweb/diakok/belepes.jsp")
        .method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();

Connection.Response login = Jsoup
        .connect("http://www.gszi.sulinet.hu/dinaweb/diakok/belepes.jsp")
        .data("jelszo","SOMETEXT")
        .data("felnev","PASSWORD")
        .cookies(initial.cookies())
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

Document page = Jsoup
        .connect("ANY_PAGE_INSIDE_THE_SITE")
        .cookies(login.cookies()) //use this with any page you parse. it will log you in
        .get();
```

Comment: Yes you're rigth thank you. Now I'm not sure how I should go to another page while stay logged in?

Comment: I've updated my post. Please don't forget to accept the answer if this solved your problem

Comment: can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73572751/jsoup-login-cookies-are-not-working-with-sub-pages-but-only-with-home-page, your solution is not working in my case.