# jSoup connection is pulling a login page

Tags: java, session, jsoup, session-cookies

I've logged into the website and got to the page i want to crawl to. Copied the URL from address bar, then connected to that using jsoup as below

`public Document getDoc() throws IOException {
        String url = "https://.......";
        Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
        for (Entry<String, String> cookie : cookies.entrySet()) {
            connection.cookie(cookie.getKey(), cookie.getValue());
        }
        Response response = connection.execute();
        cookies.putAll(response.cookies());
        return response.parse();
    }`

But this document pulls a login page and what i expect is the dom of page I want to crawl (as i already have active session in chrome). So i believe when I connect using jSoup I need to pass active session data as parameter. Is there a way I can pic active session cookie from windows directory C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Session Storage and use that to fetch active session and hence the page i want and not the login page

Comment: I did get an answer to using this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie

Comment: Then maybe you should consider deleting the question, since it's a duplicate.