# JSOUP login on website doesn`t work

Tags: java, jsoup

I want to use JSOUP for a automatical login on the website http://www.footballdatabase.eu. For that I read some advices on stackoverflow, but it didn't help me.

So for make login on current website, I used this code, but it doesn't login:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.footballdatabase.eu")
                .data("login", "mylog")
                .data("password", "mypass")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();


Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.footballdatabase.eu")
    .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
    .get();

System.out.println(document);
```

Comment: It seems you are sending this request to the main page of the site. You need to find the URL that actually performs the login, like in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6432970/jsoup-posting-and-cookie. I took a quick look at the page source but I could not find it straightaway

Comment: i solved this problem by adding  another parametres to connection response such as crealog, connect.x, connect.y. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for my problem:

```
Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://www.footballdatabase.eu")
                .data("crealog","1")
                .data("login", "mylogin")
                .data("password", "mypass")
                .data("connect.x","number1")
                .data("connect.y","number2")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.footballdatabase.eu").cookies(loginForm.cookies()).get();
```